# value attribute in hbs not showing string after space

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, hbs

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2"
                                     name="productName" value={{product.productName}} >
```

Inside my product.productName = Smart Phones, but it only shows 'Smart' inside the input field

How to show may whole string in my input field in HBS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please provide quotes for the value. I think this will help you to figure out the error:

eg:

```
value="{{product.productName}}"
```